# Finding which dependency includes what

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I currently have a warning in my `build.gradle` about support libraries not using the same version.

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.1, 23.4.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0

I do not actually include `cardview-v7:23.4.0` and I'm trying to find out which library I'm using does.

What's the easiest way to see this?

And there is also a good way to see method counts of the libraries too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can plug in the dependency here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.bloder%7Cmagic%7C1.0%7Caar) and find out what dependencies the dependency has from the pom or read my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814814/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification/47815634#47815634) its more better to call them transitive dependencies